# Alternative for T-SQL on date calculation for where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, calculated-field

I have a SQL data calculation  which is used as part of where clause  to get bookings from calculated date at midnight.

My solution:

```
bookDate >= (SELECT DATEADD(dd, -7, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))
```

The original was:

```
bookDate >= DATEADD(dd, -7, GETDATE())
```

However it returns at calculated date + current time

Is there a alternative and far simpler approach to this?

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server?? In SQL Server 2008 and newer, you could use the `DATE` datatype which is date-only - no time portion involved

Comment: it won't matter since it will only be calculated 1 time and then applied to each row.

Comment: @KM. Of course it matters. Even when it doesn't matter, it matters. People asking the questions often can't determine whether it matters or not.

Comment: I'm currently using SQL 2008.Sorry for the delay in replying back but the date datatype worked in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit simpler.

```
bookDate >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()) - 7, 0)
```

In SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2012 you can use the `date` data type.

```
bookDate >= DATEADD(dd, -7, CAST(GETDATE() as DATE))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will also work for 2005:

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, -7, FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)))
```

This works because SQL Server (and windows, for that matter) stores a date as a floating point, with the whole number representing the number of days is 01/01/1900, and the fraction part representing the time. The following is shorter, and more consistent with what I usually use in this situation:

```
SELECT FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT) -7)
```

DATEADD is useful if you're calculating on something other than days (i.e. months, years), because of the varying number of days is each given month or year. When working with days, it's often easier to add or subtract directly. Similarly, if you wanted to subtract, for example, two hours from a date, you can use:

```
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT) * 2.0/24.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it like this:

```
bookDate >= CAST(CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE() ,112) as datetime)
```